# Lambda return method which calls method that throws exception

Tags: java, exception, methods, return, throw

I have following issue.
I'm working within a `method 1` and this `method 1` should return an object of a certain class.
For my return statement I call another `method 2` (which of course returns an object of said class). Though this other `method 2` throws an exception. How should I write my return statement in my initial `method 1`?

Like this?

```
public class testClass {

    public testClass() {
    }

    public <T> T method1(parameter1, ...) {

     if(parameter1) {
      return () -> {
       try {
        method2(parameter1, parameter2...);
       } 
       catch (CloneNotSupportedException ex) {
        System.err.print("Error while cloning programmer");
       }
      };
    } else {
    return null;
    }
}
```

But I guess if I do this it will only return null?
Should i put the return null after the last bracket? Or should i write this in a totally different way?

Comment: hi there. it looks like the code you wrote in your question isn't correctly formatted java. It's helpful if your code is at least close to runnable (e.g. you don't have to stub in all the methods, but at least make it possible for others to do so without much effort)

Comment: The call for `method2` may succeed and may throw an exception, but in any case it will perform what comes after the try and catch blocks, which is returning null. You can modify it as you like. I don't have all your code so I cant know what you want to do there. Give us more information so we could help you further.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my post. Thanks for the advice. Basically normally the exception should never be thrown. I should always be getting that object from method2. I presume in case the exception is still thrown i have to put the return null in my catch-brackets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit. You wrote

> Basically normally the exception should never be thrown

That's a perfect usecase for a `RuntimeException`.  It's basically a transparent exception. Users of your code won't see it, but it will appear like a wild Pokemon when something extraordinary happens, and will make your application come to a stop, giving you a chance to fix it.

Your standard code flow won't be affected, and you'll avoid returning a `null` value.

---

*Lambda* expressions aren't allowed to throw checked `Exception`s.
`CloneNotSupportedException` extends `Exception`.

[image]

Now, you have two options

- Handle the `Exception` in-place, as you did
- Propagate the `Exception` by wrapping it in a `RuntimeException`

---

```
return () -> {
    try {
       method2(parameter1, parameter2...);
    } catch (final CloneNotSupportedException e) {
       throw YourCustomRuntimeException("Error while cloning", e /* Original cause */);
    }
};
```

This depends on the usecase, but I think `CloneNotSupportedException` **signals a bug**, which should be evident to you, developer. So let it surface.

The custom `Exception` just need to extend `RuntimeException`, and, maybe, provide additional fields to store relevant data.

```
YourCustomRuntimeException extends RuntimeException { ... }
```

**Do not** throw the base `RuntimeException`, use custom ones.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your very usefull answer. That explains a lot. Normally this exception should never occur, so I don't really have any use-case for it, or I don't really have wrote code in the case it is thrown. What do you mean by 'signals a bug, which should be evident to you. So let it surface.?' What do you mean by 'signals a bug?' and by 'Let it surface'? Otherwise, I'll just use what you gave me and make my own exception-class which implements RunTimeException.

Comment: @SimonartM I mean that this behavior isn't what you'd expect, and you **cannot recover** from it apparently. "Letting it surface" means letting your app crash basically. Is that okay for you? Or do you want to recover from an error like that? (I wouldn't)